# verifying whether file exists or not in a specified drive and its subfolders?

Tags: windows, cmd

I am using windows OS. I am trying to find out whether a specific file exists or not in a directory. currently i am using below command.

```
d:\> c:\Desktop\some.exe
```

but the problem is above command does not verify in sub folders of d drive. how can i write the command to look even in subfolders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all files in subdirectories with this command

```
dir "yourfilename.ext" /s /b
```

If you want to know is how many times your file "yourfilename.ext" is present then you could extend the previous command with

```
dir "yourfilename.ext" /s /b | find /C "yourfilename.ext"
```